# How can I sort an array of weekday strings?

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter

I start out with:

```
var weekdays = ["Sunday", "Friday", "Tuesday"]
```

I need it changed to:

```
weekdays = ["Sunday", "Tuesday", "Friday"]
```

I've converted them to Ints:

```
var days = [Int]()

for day in weekdays {

    let formatterWeekday = NSDateFormatter()

    formatterWeekday.dateFormat = "e"

    let weekday = formatterWeekday.dateFromString(day)

    let weekdayString = formatterWeekday.stringFromDate(weekday!)

    let dayInt = Int(weekdayString)

    days.append(dayInt!)

}

days.sortInPlace()
```

Which then gives me:

```
days = [1,3,6]
```

So then how do I convert `Int`s to weekday strings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you considered the simple approach?

Updated with `@Martin R` input

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter() 
// dateFormatter.weekdaySymbols = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]


for dayIndex in days
{    
    print(dateFormatter.weekdaySymbols[dayIndex])
}
```

Comment: Note that `NSCalendar` has a property `weekdaySymbols` which gives you the (localized) weekday names.

Comment: @Russell be aware that weekdaySymbols are locale dependant. You should make sure to add NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")